# Load Binary Data From a File via ActiveRecord Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there an easy (or generally accepted) way to load up a binary column using the create method of ActiveRecord?

For example, what I'm trying to do is something similar to this:

```
MyTableObject.create(name: 'Test', image: File.read('PathToMyFile.jpg'))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be ... unless I'm just doing it wrong.  The create method returns true and I do see the record in the DB; however, the image isn't recoverable and the reported filesize doesn't match up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this working.  Rather than doing:

```
MyTableObject.create(
    name: 'Test',
    image: File.read('PathToMyFile.jpg')
)
```

which **did** insert a record into the database but without the correct binary representation of the file

```
MyTableObject.create(
    name: 'Test',
    image: File.open('PathToMyFile.jpg', 'rb').read
)
```

seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Looks like a Windows-only problem - in Windows (but not unix-alikes like Linux or OSX) binary and text files are handled differently, hence the need for the explicit 'rb' mode param to correctly load the file.

Comment: Not a Windows-only problem. I had the same problem with a UNIX system (XUBUNTU, to be precise). And the recommended solution also worked on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `binread` https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/IO.html#binread-method

```
MyTableObject.create(name: 'Test', image: File.binread('PathToMyFile.jpg'))
```